# If statement php doesnt work

Tags: php, if-statement

I´ve got the following data:

```
Item 1
Title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Language: Deutsch

Item 2
Title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Language: Deutsch

Item 3
Title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Language: Englisch

Item 4
Title: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Language: Franzoesisch
```

And I want that only the "Deutsch" items are displayed in the case ("dev.domain.de"), the "Englisch" items are displayed in the case ("dev.domain.com") and so on.

```
 <?php 
      $strRendersettings = ($this->settings)? 'settings' : 'view';
 ?>
 <?php
      if (count($this->data)):
 ?>
    <ul>
      <?php
        switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
        {
            case ("dev.domain.de"):
                if ($arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl'] == "Deutsch"){
                    foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                        <li class="new_doc_home"><a href="" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                                <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                            <?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl']; ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                }
                break;

            case ("dev.domain.com"):
                foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                    <li class="new_doc_home"><a href="" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                            <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                        <?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl']; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php
                endforeach;
                break;

            case ("dev.domain.fr"):
                foreach ($this->data as $arrItem): ?>
                    <li class="new_doc_home"><a href="" ><strong><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']; ?>:</strong><br>
                            <p><?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']; ?></p></a>
                        <?php echo $arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl']; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php
                endforeach;
                break;
        }
        ?>
    </ul>

<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You have to select the data according to your hosts. And build them togheter just once.

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Which if statement doesn't work??

Comment: The error is, that the code doesnt display only the items that contain "Deutsch".
 if ($arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl'] == "Deutsch")

Comment: You have completely the same code in each case block, aren't you?

Comment: And what's the value of `$arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl']`? Post a `var_dump` of this variable. Perhaps the value es "deutsch" or something else

Comment: If you want to solve the error, just move the if statement into the foreach loop. but you have a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of **if** and **foreach** in first case are wrong. See fixed and optimized variant:

```
<?php $strRendersettings = ($this->settings)? 'settings' : 'view'; ?>
<?php if (count($this->data)): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
        $match = "";
        switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
        {
            case "dev.domain.de":
                $match = "Deutsch";
                break;

            case "dev.domain.com":
                $match = "Englisch";
                break;

            case "dev.domain.fr":
                $match = "Franzoesisch";
                break;

        }

        foreach ($this->data as $arrItem) {
            if ($arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl'] == $match){
                ?>
                <li class="new_doc_home"><a href="" ><strong><?=$arrItem['text']['new_docs_titel']?>:</strong><br></a>
                        <p><a href="" ><?=$arrItem['text']['new_docs_Text']?></a></p>
                    <?=$arrItem['text']['new_docs_auswahl']?>
                </li>
                <?
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and please, check W3C about tag nesting order.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode for this could be:

```
switch(host)
{
   case "de":
       select german data;
       break;
   case "fr":
       select french data;
       break;
   case "en":
   default:
       select english data;
       break;
 }

 foreach data as item
       display list element with item
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain this a litte bit to me, my php knowledge is not very god

Comment: Okay, let's suppose you fetch your data from a database. In this case, just select the right data for every host you want to serve.

And afterwards, you have to build the list just once. (No code duplication)

Comment: @LydiaMaier Basically a `switch/case` only references the variable (which in the above example is `host`) **ONCE**, no nested `if/else` blocks. This way is also more maintainable and a cleaner way of producing what you need to do.

Comment: @LydiaMaier It's not at all difficult. It's a clean and smart way of coding :) just try it out and experiment with it. [Here are the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)